# Если серверная часть написана на Java, можно ли написать клиент на js+html, не используя jsp.

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jsf

Для учебных целей хочу создать приложение: форум,  где участники могут регистрироваться,  оставлять сообщения(чтобы сообщения сохранялись в бд). Приложение будет написано на  Java.  Можно ли обойтись без использования  jsp,  jsf,  а только  html и js? Буду очень благодарен ответившим.

Comment: Вполне возможно. Ничто не запрещает вам обращаться к бэкэнду через js, а на основе полученных данных строить страницу на стороне клиента. [Здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_get2) пример обращения.

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Вам успешно подойдет [RESTfull](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) архитектура.

Клиент с сервером по-прежнему общаются по http-протоколу, только теперь в ответах сервер отдает уже не готовые html-странички, а состояния (по сути данные) запрошенных вами ресурсов(URI) в формате json или реже xml. JS на клиенте разбирает эти ответы и сам строит необходимые странички.

Таким образом между клиентом и сервером нет больше никакой связи, кроме четко формализованного Rest Api. Причем клиент может быть реализован на чем угодно, HTML+JS это лишь частный случай. Это не новый, но очень популярный подход сейчас.